# Как в список списка добавить элементы из другого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два списка

```
a = [['Один', 'Два', 'Три'], ['Четыре', 'Пять', 'Шесть']]

b = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

Нужно чтобы получилось так:

```
c = [['Один', 'Два', 'Три', '1', '2'], ['Четыре', 'Пять', 'Шесть', '3', '4']]
```

Спасибо :)

Comment: print([x + z for x, z in zip(a, b)])

Comment: Спасибо огромное! :)

Answer (score -1):

Пример кода через `zip`:

```
c = []
for lst1, lst2 in zip(a, b):
    lst1.extend(lst2)
    c.append(lst1)
```

еще можно так:

```
c = [lst1 + lst2 for lst1, lst2 in zip(a, b)]
```

можно проще, через `extend`

```
c = [i.extend(j) or i for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

Можно применить генератор списков и оператор `+` для конкатенации элементов из двух списков:

```
c = [i + j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: `extend` поменяет исходный список, а судя по вопросу, на выходе ожидается новый список, а изменение старого не ожидается. Кроме того, `extend` ничего не возвращает, так что последний пример вообще не корректный.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: А, нет, я был не совсем прав, что будет ошибка, удалил этот комментарий, но всё-равно не используйте методы, ничего не возвращающие, в списочных сокращениях. Неправильно это.